# How to store row style changed by callback event when switching between table pages in DT?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I’m trying to create a table in Shiny app in which a user can highlight rows on double click.

Here is my code:

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)

js.highlight.func <- "table.on('dblclick','tr',function(){$(this).toggleClass('red')})"

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        tags$head(
            tags$style(HTML(".red { background-color: red !important; }"))
            ),
        DTOutput('tbl')),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$tbl = renderDT(
            callback = JS(js.highlight.func),
            iris
        )
    }
)
```

My problem is that it doesn’t remain highlighting when I select another table page and then return back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the option `server=FALSE`:

```
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT({
      datatable(iris, callback = JS(js.highlight.func))
    }, server = FALSE)
  }
```